# Select Max date with multiple DATETIME values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for information from a database to find the latest time in a datetime column. Sometimes there are multiple times a process finishes each day and i only want to see the latest of that day.

I have tried an INNER JOIN statment but i am returning MAX Date.

Data Example below:

```
Time                 |    Product
2019-01-01-22:15     |    CHEESE
2019-01-01-22:35     |    CHEESE
2019-01-02-22:35     |    CHEESE
2019-01-02-22:37     |    CHEESE
```

To show as

```
Time                 |    Product
2019-01-01-22:35     |    CHEESE
2019-01-02-22:37     |    CHEESE
```

This will be for multiple products

*** EDIT ***

I need this for multiple dates of the month

*** EDIT ***
It will be for other Products on the day to, Cheese is one example of them

so:

```
 Time                 |    Product
    2019-01-01-22:15     |    CHEESE
    2019-01-01-22:35     |    CHEESE
    2019-01-01-22:45     |    BREAD
    2019-01-01-22:57     |    BREAD
    2019-01-02-22:35     |    CHEESE
    2019-01-02-22:37     |    CHEESE
    2019-01-02-22:35     |    BREAD
    2019-01-02-22:37     |    BREAD
```

To show as

```
Time                 |    Product
2019-01-01-22:35     |    CHEESE
2019-01-01-22:57     |    BREAD
2019-01-02-22:37     |    CHEESE
2019-01-02-22:37     |    BREAD
```

Comment: @HoneyBadger There isnt anything wrong with the data

Comment: You are only showing one product. How do you want the result when there are different products per day? Are you looking for the last product then or do you want a row per day and product actually?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Updated Question

Comment: Okay. As you can see from the answers, you confused some people into thinking you wanted the last product per day. One row per product and day is `group by product, day` in SQL. You get from datetime to day by casting it. See Michał Turczyn's answer or Yogesh Sharma's for that matter.

Comment: Aside: Using keywords, reserved words, data types and the like as misleading object names is not a "best practice". Having to wrap `Time` in square brackets gets tedious and since it contains a date it is confusing. Using a past tense verb and "On" often makes sense are tends not to collide with existing names: `ProcessedOn`, `CreatedOn`, `InspectedOn`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use `top 1 with ties` and `row_number` with casting:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES [Time], Product
FROM TableName
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
    PARTITION BY Product, CAST([Time] AS Date) 
    ORDER BY CAST([Time] AS Time) DESC)
```

The `row_number` will return 1 for the latest time in each date.

Another option would be to use a common table expression (or a derived table) like this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT [Time], 
           Product,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
               PARTITION BY Product, CAST([Time] AS Date) 
               ORDER BY CAST([Time] AS Time) DESC) As Rn
    FROM TableName
)
SELECT [Time], Product
FROM CTE
WHERE Rn = 1
```

This way you can decide how you want to order the results.

Comment: Fantastic answer and helping me to look into WITH TIES but it doesnt work with multiple products for a date, i have updated the question

Comment: So you want the last row for each product in each day? If that's the case, all you need is to add the Product to the partition by clause. See my edited answer.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you Zohar

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 4):

Why this is not sufficient ?

```
select product, max(time)
from table t
group by product, cast(t.time as date);
```

However, if you have a more columns then you need `subquery` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.time = (select max(t1.time)
                from table t1
                where cast(t1.time as date) = cast(t.time as date) and
                      t1.product = t.product
               );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Product, MAX([Time]) FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Product, CAST([Time] AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.time = (select max(t2.time)
                from t t2
                where convert(date, t2.time) = convert(date, t.time)
               );
```

Comment: Updated Question